# Will a core2duo required processor game playable with P4 3.06ghz processor

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gaming

I want to play transformers-fall-of-cybertron PC game but the minimum requirement is Core2Duo processor.

All other minimum requirement is more than enough except for CPU .

**My question is : Will I be able to play this game smoothly, since CPU is only the problem but GPU is more than enough.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt it. Your CPU is vastly inferior to the minimum recommended CPU, which has more than four times the performance of your P4 3.06.

You have the same problem with your GPU too. Your GPU gets about 470 3DMarks. The minimum GPUs get around 1900.

Comment: So, its impossible to play this game smoothly?

Comment: With that hardware, definitely impossible.